# Is there existing support in tomcat for a JDBCRealm that takes in a salt?

Tags: security, tomcat, jdbcrealm

We are currently using tomcat 5.5 and would like to add a salt to our JDBCRealm authentication.  I was wondering if there was any existing classes or do we need to extend JDBCRealm and write our own authentication class?

We have the following in our server.xml

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" ...more stuff… />
```

But it does not look like this class takes in a salt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write your own `JDBCRealmWithSalt` class that extends `JDBCRealm` class
2. Overwrite `digest()` method (add your salt here)
3. Put `JDBCRealmWithSalt` in `catalina.jar:org/apache/catalina/realm`
4. `<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealmWithSalt"...>`

Answer (score 1):

No existing classes as in built-in to the Tomcat 5.5 APIs, so you will have to use a custom one.

One example can be found at http://eneuwirt.de/2011/05/01/saltawarejdbcrealm/

Comment: Tomcat 7 may have something out of the box as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053552/tomcat-7-11-jdbcrealm-and-userdatabaserealm-dont-work-together

Comment: Sadly, eneuwirt.de is gone now.

Comment: But the code [lives on](https://github.com/eneuwirt/fbs/blob/master/fbs-security/src/main/java/com/fbs/security/shiro/realm/SaltAwareJdbcRealm.java).

Answer (score 0):

As of Tomcat 8 for any shipped out-of-the-box Realm you can specify:

- the desired algorithm
- the encoding to be used
- salt
- number of iterations
- key length

You would provide these in `CATALINA_HOME/bin/digest.[bat|sh]`

For more information: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html