# Tomcat 7.11 JDBCRealm and UserDatabaseRealm dont work together

Tags: security, tomcat, tomcat7, realm, jdbcrealm

I'm trying to set a container managerd security a realm for my web app (JSF 2.1 + hibernate). I have noticed that Tomcat 7 can only use one type of realm at a time.

To use Tomcat in netbeans (7.0) i have to create an accout of manager-script role. In addition to work with Tomcat manager I also need another role. This is a big problem for me because the tables I'm using for JDBCRealm are viewes from actual tables that store users and roles and I would like not to store both of the roles in the same db that my program uses.

Is there a way to make JDBCRealm and UserDBRealm work together? That would be a relief.

here is the code from server.config:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
    driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/realm?user=login&amp;password=pass" 
    userTable="users"
    userNameCol="user_name"
    userCredCol="user_pass"
    userRoleTable="user_roles" 
    roleNameCol="role_name" />
```

tomcat uses only the last one he finds in the file. They work fine separetly

Comment: In theory, you could create a custom realm.

Comment: I will think about that. By the way Your blog rules. I have found many answers to my problems there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CombinedRealm` ([doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm), [javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/CombinedRealm.html)):

> Realm implementation that contains one or more realms. Authentication
>   is attempted for each realm in the order they were configured. If any
>   realm authenticates the user then the authentication succeeds. When
>   combining realms usernames should be unique across all combined
>   realms.

Maybe you are already using the `LockOutRealm` ([doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#LockOutRealm), [javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/LockOutRealm.html)) which is a subclass of `CombinedRealm` and it's in the default config of Tomcat.

Comment: Yes I was using LockOutRealm but usernames where not unique across realms. I ensured that my program will not use the same names as there are in tomcat-users.xml. Works as a charm now. Thank You very much